# Python counts 2 backslashes as 4?

Tags: python

So, basically I'm trying to put a variable in a directory string, so here's what I got

```
os.startfile(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\Alfred\start\\'+sentence+".exe")
```

But when I'm trying to run the script (the other code doesn't have anything to do with this error), this comes up:

```
    os.startfile(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\Alfred\Open\\'+sentence+'.exe')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Alfred\\Open\\\\badlion.exe'
```

It somehow counts "\\" as "\\\\", when I try to put "\" instead of "\\" it counts the variable (sentence), as a string???
Please help, I'm new to Python.

Comment: It's a raw string. \ in a raw string is \\ in a normal string. \\ in a raw string is therefore \\\\

Comment: can you print `sentence`? it seems as if it also contain `\\`

Comment: Basically, I'm making a virtual assistant, and it will do things for you, I'm positive I didn't accidentally say "backslash"

Comment: That's just the way backslashes are *represented*

Comment: I said "bob open badlion", and since I used code to remove "bob" and "open", it prints "badlion"

Comment: What is sentence? And can your run: print(type(sentence))

Comment: How about `f-strings`? `os.startfile(f"C:\Users\User\Downloads\Alfred\start\{sentence}.exe")`

Comment: <class 'str'>, im not quite sure what that means

Comment: Anyway, the problem here is that even raw strings will do some primitive backslash processing, namely, for quote-chars, so, raw strings cannot end with an odd-number of backslashes. You can read about it at the bottom of [this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: PythonSherpa, a bunch of errors come up on my  IDE

Error:

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Now it says "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape" and it points to the "f"

Comment: Are you *trying* to put two backslashes there? Because that is, in fact, what you are doing

Comment: As I said in the post, if I put 1 backslash instead of 2, it contains the variable inside the string

Comment: **What are you trying to do**? And **again** what version of Python are you using? Note, `'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Alfred\\Open\\\\badlion.exe'` is a string with *two* backslashes there at the end, not 4. Go ahead and `print('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Alfred\\Open\\\\badlion.exe')` Did you want two? Or one?

Comment: I'm trying to have the script open a program, but as I said multiple times, if I put 1 backslash instead of 2 it will count the variable after it as a string, and if I don't have the r, it will also count the variable as a string.

Comment: @CraftYun83 I didn't ask you that, *I understand that*, **please answer my question**: do you want **one** or *two* backslashes? **What version of python are you using**. If it's *one* maybe the easiest is to use the answer by @TimurU but really, you should be using `pathlib`

Comment: I want 1 backslash because 2 backslashes are not a valid directory. Im using Python 3.8, and @TimurU's answer didn't works since there is 2 backslashes

Comment: @CraftYun83 no, Timur's solution **only has single backslashes**. Go ahead an `print('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Alfred\\start\\'+sentence+".exe")`, what do you see?

Comment: @CraftYun83 the representation of a string with a single backslash in Python produces two backslashes. __But the string itself still contains only one backslash__.

Answer (score 2):

R string may give error with end symbol  
But not error using \ - double slash

Use:

```
os.startfile('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Alfred\\start\\'+sentence+".exe")
```

But this type:

```
r’some text\’
```

may be error end of string

```
r’some text\\’
```

Will give double slash at end

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222688/discussion-on-answer-by-timur-u-python-counts-2-backslashes-as-4).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to workaround the problem with the `\` at the end of your raw-string, in this case you may also use formatted-raw-strings:

```
os.startfile(fr'C:\Users\User\Downloads\Alfred\start\{sentence}.exe')
```

Provided, of course, the file under that path actually exists on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between raw string literals, normal strings, and how [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) deals with them.

```
raw = r"raw string: \ \\ \\\\"
normal = "normal string: \ \\ \\\\"

print(raw, repr(raw), normal, repr(normal), sep='\n')
```

Outputs:

```
raw string: \ \\ \\\\         
'raw string: \\ \\\\ \\\\\\\\'
normal string: \ \ \\         
'normal string: \\ \\ \\\\'
```

- Every slash in a raw string literal is treated as an actual slash
- The path in the exception message is rendered using `repr()`

Therefore, each slash in your raw string literal will add two slashes in the exception message. But there's only one slash in the variable, and that's what python functions will see:

```
> print(raw[-1], normal[-1])

\ \
```

Comment: If I put 1 backslash instead of 2 it thinks "sentence"( a variable) is a string...

Comment: @CraftYun83 What do you mean "it thinks sentence is a string"? The answer above shows why your traceback looks like there are more slashes than you've added. You have 1 slash in each path segment and 2 before `+ sentence` , so the exception will show 2 slashes between each directory in the path, and 4 (r`'\' * 2`) right before `sentence`.

Comment: @CraftYun83 yes, because then it escapes the single-quote

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what double quote..?

Comment: @BłażejMichalik I misspoke, I meant single-quote, `r'blah blah blah \' blah blah blha'` is one big string, because `\'` still escapes the quote in a raw string.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga still, not the case here. It happens only if the single-quote is unbalanced, which is not the case in OPs question.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik sure, but I'm almost certain taht is what the OP is referring to when they said: "when I try to put "\" instead of "\\" it counts the variable (sentence), as a string" which is not a case the OP is showing.

Comment: @CraftYun83 ok, please show how exactly the line of your code that lead to "it thinks `sentence` is a string" looks.

Comment: I can't comment pictures

Comment: @CraftYun83 you don't need pictures.

Comment: In Pycharm, string is green, variables are white, the variable "sentence" is green, not white

Comment: @CraftYun83 just copy-paste it. Why you want to use pictures? We just want to see the line, we don't need to see how pycharm highlights it

Comment: Anyway, just use `os.startfile(fr'C:\Users\User\Downloads\Alfred\start\{sentence}.exe)'`...

Comment: os.startfile('C:\Users\User\Downloads\Alfred\open\'+sentence+'.exe')

Comment: doesn't work... is there any other module besides os, that can open files and will actually work?

Comment: @CraftYun83 that module works. **Again** your path is *incorrect*. This is not the a problem with `os`